# NgbModal not opening modal from component included in another component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using `Anuglar 6`

I have two components `account` and `profile`. **account** component is added to the **app-component**.

I want to open up **profile-component** on click of a button from **account-component**.

But this is giving me an error

```
Error: No component factory found for NgbModalBackdrop. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

the **app-module** looks like

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, AccountComponent, ProfileComponent ],
  entryComponents: [
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwobqm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a big of a vague guess but you probably need to import the NgbModule like so in your app.module.ts

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
```

That should then fix the error you're running into.

Comment: Can't see the error anymore, in the link you shared

Comment: oops, i got confused. I am talking about the one shared above, by Sunil Singh. It seems to work fine

Comment: is there any other way? It makes the module havier to load. (It loads the whole module...... which is more than 100 kB in gzipped state!)

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me by adding NgbModule at my module file.

```
import {  NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
     imports: [...
     NgbModule,
      ....],
     declarations: [],
     entryComponents: [...]
     })
```